# QuickSort not working, think swap is the issue, Disclaimer I must use the quicksort method provided to me

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort, swap

```
try {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                working[i] = data[i];
            }

            FileWriter fw3 = new FileWriter("quicksort.dat");

            long startTime3 = System.nanoTime();

            quickSort(working,0, working.length - 1);

            long endTime3 = System.nanoTime();

            long totalTime3 = endTime3 - startTime3;

            System.out.println("The time to complete the quick sort was :" + totalTime3 + " nano seconds");

            for (i = 0; i < working.length; i++) {
                fw3.write(Integer.toString(working[i]) + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println("The file has been sorted by quick sort and output to quicksort.dat \n");

            fw3.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }




static void quickSort(int data[], int left, int right) {

        int i, j;
        int partition;
        if (right > left) {
            partition = data[right];
            i = left - 1;
            j = right;

            for (;;) {
                while (data[++i] < partition);
                while (data[--j] > partition);
                if (i >= j) {
                    break;
                }
                swap(data[i], data[j]);
                swap(data[i], data[right]);
                quickSort(data, left, i - 1);
                quickSort(data, i + 1, right);

            }
        }
    }

    static void swap(int left, int right) {
        int array[] = new int[19];
        int temp = array[left];
        array[left] = array[right];
        array[right]=temp;
```

This is just snippets of the code whole program is other sorts. I get an out bounds error every time it gets down to the quicksort function. I use 19 as my array because that is how big the file is I have tried 20 to see if it fixes it with no luck.

EDIT: I provided updated code down below to reflect changes that were made I still get an out of bounds error.

```
    static void quickSort(int data[], int left, int right) {

    int i, j;
    int partition;
    if (right > left) {
        partition = data[right];
        i = left - 1;
        j = right;

        for (;;) {
            while (data[++i] < partition);
            while (data[--j] > partition);
            if (i >= j) {
                break;
            }
            swap(data, i, j);
            swap(data, i, right);
            quickSort(data, left, i - 1);
            quickSort(data, i + 1, right);

        }
    }
}


static void swap(int array[], int left, int right) {
     int temp = array[left];        
     array[left] = array[right];    
     array[right] = temp;          

}
```

Comment: is this java?  Consider adding a language tag

Comment: yes it is java just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared swap as :

```
void swap(int left, int right)
```

So the arguments are the indexes into the array.

However, you call it with :

```
swap(data[i], data[j]);
```

So you are passing the VALUES in the array.

Try changing the call to :

```
swap(i, j);
```

EDIT TO ADD:

It must be pointed out that the issue above is just ONE issue with the sorting algorithm presented.  Another problem is that the `swap` algorithm does not actually swap anything.   It creates a local array variable `array`, operates on that and then returns (so discarding that local variable).

If your assignment is to output a sorted list of numbers, and that the numbers must be sorted using the sorting code presented - then that assignment is impossible because the sorting code presented is hopelessly flawed as a sorting algorithm;  it does NOT sort (as you have found yourself), and has blatant severe issues compared to a correct implementation of quicksort (eg, you can compare to the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63811974/681444 )

EDIT TO ADD FOLLOWING REVISED CODE:

The revised sorting code is STILL hopelessly busted.   It is not a correct implementation of QuickSort, and still does not sort correctly.

For example, I tried running it with the final element being the largest :

```
int data[] = {23, 8, 19, 35, 2, 12, 7, 64 };
```

Result : No sorting - the method hit the `if (i >= j) {break;}` with i==7 and j==6 straight off and so did nothing.

By contrast, the method in the answer I linked to above sorted correctly, so you can compare the method you have been given against that - or against other established articles (eg, do an internet search for `java quicksort`, there are plenty around)

Comment: I will try this for sure, but I will have to probably find a solution as the professor unfortunately wants his quicksort method to be untouched. But I appreciate it and will try this.

Comment: Let me know how it goes - the other thing you could do try changing the array (and the quicksort) from int to String so that will really differentiate (ie give compile errors!) where indexes and values are wrongly mixed

Comment: Well the swap did not work but the array has to be int since the file we sorting is all integers.

Comment: Thank you for your help he did admit he made an error but I seem to still not be able to get it to work. I will update my original post.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by ['racraman'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681444/racraman), the sort definitely requires fixing.

Try re-implementing the sort function with the following method signature.

```
void sort(int[] arr, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
// swap code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yeah the professor was wrong gave us C++ code I have tried what he suggested again but I'm still getting an error. I also fixed the swap method to work with the new function.

Comment: Maybe your professor wanted you to learn the hard way or expected students to ask questions. In any case may not have guessed that the questions will end up on SO!

Comment: I am more incline to believe that it was a mistake based off my knowledge of him and how he operates.

Comment: @ngzg611 - If this is C++ code, then the swap can be implemented as originally shown, using references in the swap function: `swap (int &left, int &right)` .